# Angularjs, value coming in token from backend not working in client side

Tags: angularjs, token

What is wrong with the code it's not working, I am trying to request call web service from backend written in spring, the value passing from backend is token wrapped, I am trying to run the code on client side but form is not passing any value.

**auth.js**

```
'use strict';

angular. module('app')
        .factory('Auth', [ '$http', '$rootScope', '$window', 'Session', 'AUTH_EVENTS',
            function($http, $rootScope, $window, Session, AUTH_EVENTS) {
                var authService = {};
                this.isLoggedIn = function isLoggedIn(){
                    return session.getUser() !== null;
                };

                //the login function
                authService.login = function(user, success, error) {
                    $http.post('URL: http://xxx.xxx.x.xx:xxxx/xxxx/authenticateUser').success(function(authData) {
                        //user is returned with his data from the db
                        var users = data.users;
                        if(users[user.username]){
                            var loginData = users[user.username];

                            //insert your custom login function here
                            if(user.username == loginData.username && user.password == loginData.username){

                                localStorageService.set(['userInfo'],
                                        { token: result.access_token, userName: loginData.userName });

                                //delete password no/t to be seen clientside
                                delete loginData.password;

                                //update current user into the Session service or $rootScope.currentUser
                                //whatever you prefer
                                Session.create(loginData);
                                //or
                                $rootScope.currentUser = loginData;

                                //fire event of successful login
                                $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginSuccess);
                                //run success function
                                success(loginData);
                            } else{
                                //OR ELSE
                                //unsuccessful login, fire login failed event for
                                //the according functions to run
                                $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginFailed);
                                error();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                };

                //check if the user is authenticated
                authService.isAuthenticated = function() {
                    return !!Session.user;
                };

                //check if the user is authorized to access the next route
                //this function can be also used on element level
                //e.g. <p ng-if="isAuthorized(authorizedRoles)">show this only to admins</p>
                authService.isAuthorized = function(authorizedRoles) {
                    if (!angular.isArray(authorizedRoles)) {
                        authorizedRoles = [authorizedRoles];
                    }
                    return (authService.isAuthenticated() &&
                    authorizedRoles.indexOf(Session.userRole) !== -1);
                };

                //log out the user and broadcast the logoutSuccess event
                authService.logout = function(){
                    Session.destroy();
                    localStorageService.removeItem("userInfo");
                    $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.logoutSuccess);
                }

                return authService;
            } ]);
```

**authInterceptor**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('app');
    var factoryId = 'authInterceptor';

    app.factory(factoryId, authInterceptor);

    authInterceptor.$inject = ['$q', '$location', 'localStorageService', $rootScope, $http];

    function authInterceptor($q, $location, localStorageService) {

        var service = {
            request: request,
            responseError: responseError,
        };

        return service;

        function request(config) {

            config.headers = config.headers || {};

            var authData = localStorageService.get('authorizationData');
            if (authData) {
                config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authData.token;
            }

            return config;
        }

        function responseError(error) {
            var loggedIn = false;
            var authData = localStorageService.get('authorizationData');
            if (authData) {
                loggedIn = true;
            }
            //We only want to go to the login page if the user is not
            //logged in. If the user is logged in and they get a 401 is
            //because they don't have access to the resource requested.
            if (error.status === 401 && !loggedIn) {
                $location.path('/login').replace();
            }

            return $q.reject(error);
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Your success callback for the authentication is using a variable called `data`. Yet, your trying to read the backend auth token from a variable called `result`. I searched the code you posted and this variable only appears once. So, I'm assuming you're trying to read the auth token information from the wrong variable.

Comment: NunoM yes there was this mistake, can you help me guide to know if the other logic is right, because after changing the data value is still not passing.

Comment: There was no need to change the `data` parameter's name to `authData`. Still, in order to make sure you're getting everything you need from that POST request, please do a `console.log(authData);` right at the beginning of the success callback. You can now check your browser's console to see what the server has sent you (most likely an object with properties regarding the authentication token and its validity). Do that and you'll be able to match your variables with the server response, and only then correct the body of your function accordingly.